# Modificar elemento de un archivo Json

Tags: android-studio, json

Tengo un archivo Json igual que este como puedo modificar el elemento "url" desde mi MainActivity en android studio. Les agradecería mucho su apoyo.

```
[
  {
    "Id" : 2,
    "Url" : "https:www.facebook.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: deberías generar el json dinamicamente en vez de tenerlo en un archivo

Comment: hola, como puedo hacer eso

Comment: para que estás usando ese json? mostra el codigo de como lo usas